# Anime about people merging their bodies through the power of love with the help of gems

Tags: story-identification, anime

I watched this anime 10-15 years ago.

In the episode I watched the enemy was a woman and man that merged their bodies to create a singular body which was a super powerful version of themselves in order to fight their opponent. The woman was saying something about their power of love and how their power comes from the strength of the love between them. I think they may have used a gem to merge their bodies.

Also I believe this anime might have revolved around these types of merges by the hero's as well who also may have used a gem but I'm not sure. I only remember this specific scene.

Comment: Welcome to SFF:SE. We recommend having a look at the [tour](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/tour), which contains helpful hints for using the site. As this is a story identification question, you can also have a look at this [guide](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/tags/story-identification/info).

Comment: Far warning, TV Tropes, but http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/FusionDance might not be a bad place to look.

Comment: The power of love? Was there also something about a force from above?

Answer (score 3):

This sounds like the end of the anime series [*Maze*](https://www.animenewsnetwork.com/encyclopedia/anime.php?id=44).

The series title character is female during the day and male at night.  Later we learn that they are two characters who were in love but could not be together, which led to the fused state.  They get separated again in the last half, but in the finale fuse again to overcome the villain, who is a similarly fused character.  The villain claims she/he will become just like her/him, and Maze counters that she/he won't because of their love.

[image: Maze characters poster]